# How to display 1 hour 46 minutes in MS Excel cell where both the number count of hours and minutes comes from calculation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I sleep for 7 hours and 36 minutes. I have a sleeping threshold of 5 hours and 54 minutes. If I sleep more than threshold time, I get the time difference and If i sleep less than or equal to my sleeping threshold, i get the output as 'You slept Good". To do so, I scaled  zero to 60 minutes of actual time to 0 to 1 on a decimal scale, this way 7 hours 36 minutes comes as 7.6 and 5 hours 54 minutes comes as 5.9.

Now, I take their difference which comes out to be 1.7 i.e. I slept extra for 1 hour and 0.7 minutes on 0to1 scale (which equals 1 hour 42 minutes on actual time scale).

So, I used TRUNC function to display 1 h (i.e ! hour);  however I can't get my mind working as to how I can display 42 minutes in the same cell.

i.e. my output should be 1h 42 min

[image: What I have done so far]

Comment: Calculate in seconds and [format the output](http://www.excelfunctions.net/seconds-to-time-excel.html)

Comment: Screenshot has been edited. I took care while deleting that cell but my laptop hanged. I had to manual switch it off and switch on again. Totally forgot about it. Pardon.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still in your edit history, which might be fine. Let's see what the moderators think

Comment: Before flagging, kindly make the other person aware so that he/she can correct the errors or mistakes. I might be an unintentional error, which is in this case.

Comment: Yes, thats what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(B2+C2/60>5.9,LEFT(B2+C2/60-5.9)& "hr "&ROUND(((B2+C2/60-5.9)-VALUE(LEFT(B2+C2/60-5.9)))*60,0)&"min","You slept good")
```

However, you wouldn't be able to do further calculations, as it is a text.

Also assumes you will not oversleep by more than 10 hrs :)

Comment: Can i create the graph of Delta(Sleep) v/s date ?

Comment: Not with with solution. As I had mentioned, this returns a text. For a graph, you will need numbers. @SamneetSinghWilkhoo

Comment: For some inpus, I am getting very large decimal approximations. Is ther any solution for this ? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8u9s38201joYnVaQkVLb2tPdTg

Comment: 5 hr 55 mins to 6 hrs 4 mins, and then repeats from 6 hrs 55  mins to 7 hrs 4 mins.

Comment: more approximations can be seen as sleep hours are increased. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8u9s38201joU1JiVl8xa3BDWEk

Comment: added a rounding formula to round the minute to nearest whole number. Try now. Though am not sure what was going wrong with the previous formula @SamneetSinghWilkhoo